# Receiving Xmpp message, Attribute missing

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am developing small chat application using xmpp and ASMACK android-8-4.0.6 .On sending message, server sends me reply to acknowledge that message has successfully reached the server. and reply looks like as follows

```
<message to="abc@ofsrv1"><a xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3" h="6vO1d-7"/></message>
```

where attribute 'h' inside  element contains packet id of sent message. I am sending message as follows

```
public void sendMessage(String to, String messageData)
    {
        try
        {
            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            addMessageToLocalDb(to, messageData, msg.getPacketID());
            msg.setBody(messageData);
            DeliveryReceiptManager.addDeliveryReceiptRequest(msg);
            xmppConnection.sendPacket(msg);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

I have attach packet listener in which i am receiving server's reply but it receives in the form as follow

```
<message to='sender@ofsrv1'><a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'></a></message>
```

where 'h' attribute in  element is clearly missing. Interesting part is some where in my log cat, under "SMACK" tag i received perfect reply along with h attribute just as follows

```
<message to="sender@ofsrv1"><a xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3" h="6vO1d-7"/></message>
```

so servers reply is successfully reaching to android client but some how attached packet listener is not receiving it . code for attaching packet listener is

```
public void configureConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            //PacketFilter filter1 = new IQTypeFilter(IQ.Type.RESULT);
            PacketFilter filter = new PacketFilter()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(Packet packet)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            XmppPacketListener xmppPacketListener = new XmppPacketListener(this, xmppConnection);
            xmppConnection.addPacketListener(xmppPacketListener, filter);

            //Registering Delivery receipt Listener
            deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);
            XmppReceiptReceivedListener receiptReceivedListener = new XmppReceiptReceivedListener();
            deliveryReceiptManager.addReceiptReceivedListener(receiptReceivedListener);

            //Enabling carbons
            CarbonManager carbonManager = CarbonManager.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection);
            if (carbonManager.isSupportedByServer())
            {
                carbonManager.sendCarbonsEnabled(true);
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            CustomLogger.showLog("Xmpp", "Error in configuring xmpp connection" + e.toString());
        }
    }


public class XmppPacketListener implements PacketListener
{

    private XMPPConnection mXmppConnection;

    private Context mContext;



    public XmppPacketListener(Context context, XMPPConnection xmppConnection)
    {
        CustomLogger.showLog(TAG, "Packet listener init");
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mXmppConnection = xmppConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet)

    {

        try
        {
            CustomLogger.showLog("Message", "Received packet" + packet);



        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me to figure out what exactly i am missing in receiving packets
any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Where is the packet extension provider's code for the extension? BTW it's atypical to enclose the stream mangement `</a>` element within a message, it's a top level stream element, not a stanza extension element: Also the h attribute is specified to be the entities counter of handled stanzas, not a packet ID. You may want to tell the person who implemented that. If you need message acks, use message delivery receipts.

Comment: @Flow I am trying to achieve XEP198 on openfire .since xep198 is not supported i was sending reply as <message><a></a></message>  from server.  what you will recommend to achieve the same

Comment: @Flow nevertheless i am still wondering how can my log cat show same reply under "SMACK" tag but not received in my packet listener

Comment: Smack is open source, you could simply debug the reason.

Comment: @Flow I am trying to debug the reason by de-compiling the jar. i was able to trace the Logs with 'SMACK ' tag which are written in AndroidDebugger class but some how couldn't find reference to AndroidDebugger class and reader provided to it. can you help with attaching such listener which will receive reply sent by server

Comment: Why do you decompile the jar of a open source library?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69708/discussion-between-rohan-and-flow).